# HtmlAgilityPack Issue in reading nested html

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am having an issue with reading nested HTML nodes using HtmlAgilityPack.
I want to read all font nodes which are inside the div tag and want to process all p tags.

My logic :
I select the all p tags, now process it by using foreach loop.Then I am selecting first node from the current item.

Issue:
But it seams to be it is selecting first node from root of the html.

I want :
Is there any way to select tags from current item (node)?

I am having HTML code like this

```
 <font>State</font>
<div>
    <p>
        <font>text1</font>
        <a href="mailto:rabbi@chabadofalabama.com" target="mainFrame">EMAIL</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <font>text2</font>
        <a href="mailto:rabbi@chabadofalabama.com" target="mainFrame">EMAIL</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <font>text3</font>
        <a href="mailto:rabbi@chabadofalabama.com" target="mainFrame">EMAIL</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <font>text4</font>
        <a href="mailto:rabbi@chabadofalabama.com" target="mainFrame">EMAIL</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <font>text5</font>
        <a href="mailto:rabbi@chabadofalabama.com" target="mainFrame">EMAIL</a>
    </p>

</div>
```

My C# reading code is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter A Url :");
        var ur = Console.ReadLine();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ur));
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.UserAgent = "Foo";
        request.Accept = "*/*";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(responseString);
        var topLevelItems = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name.ToLower() == "p").ToList();

        foreach (var item in topLevelItems)
        {
            var v = item.SelectSingleNode("//font[1]");
            if(v!=null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Results : "+v.InnerText);
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You just missed a dot in your SelectSingleNode XPath. Change `item.SelectSingleNode("//font[1]");` in `item.SelectSingleNode(".//font[1]");`

Comment: I can't believe people still use HtmlAgilityPack! It's practically been around since before it was even possible to create it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you are searching in the entire document data every loop because of `//` so the foreach seems to be 'not working'

replace it with

```
var v = item.SelectSingleNode(".//font[1]");
```

now it should check data only inside `item` variable of the `foreach` loop